When i started my application, spring does not see my been of type IngredientRepository
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in tacos.web.DesignTacoController required a bean of type 'tacos.data.IngredientRepository' that could not be found.
Below controller;
package tacos.web;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import tacos.data.IngredientRepository;
import tacos.model.Ingredient;
import tacos.model.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.model.Taco;
import tacos.model.TacoOrder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class DesignTacoController {

    private final IngredientRepository ingredientRepo;

    @Autowired
    public DesignTacoController(
            IngredientRepository ingredientRepo) {
        this.ingredientRepo = ingredientRepo;
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        Iterable<Ingredient> ingredients = ingredientRepo.findAll();
        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                    filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "tacoOrder")
    public TacoOrder order() {
        return new TacoOrder();
    }

    @ModelAttribute(name = "taco")
    public Taco taco() {
        return new Taco();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm() {
        return "design";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processTaco(
            @Valid Taco taco, Errors errors,
            @ModelAttribute TacoOrder tacoOrder) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "design";
        }
        tacoOrder.addTaco(taco);
        log.info("Processing taco: {}", taco);
        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

    private Iterable<Ingredient> filterByType(
            Iterable<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(ingredients.spliterator(), false)
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}


Below Service Class;
package tacos.data;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import tacos.model.Ingredient;

@Repository
public interface IngredientRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Ingredient, String> {
}

Below run class
package tacos;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import tacos.data.IngredientRepository;
import tacos.model.Ingredient;
import tacos.model.Ingredient.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner dataLoader(IngredientRepository repo) {
        return args -> {
            repo.deleteAll();
            repo.save(new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE));
            repo.save(new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE));

        };

    }
}


Exeption:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tacos.data.IngredientRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Parameter 0 of constructor in tacos.web.DesignTacoController required a bean of type 'tacos.data.IngredientRepository' that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type 'tacos.data.IngredientRepository' in your configuration.
I do not understand everything stands normal by its packages and annotations are everywhere, I do not understand what is the problem!
